# Interstitial ad using admob not displayed in released app

Tags: android

My question is that Admob Interstitial ad is displaying in testing mode but if app is released then ad is not displayed.

like i use
    AdRequest mAdRequest;

```
mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        `enter code here`.addTestDevice("12312132654654232").build();
```

but at the time releasing app i used code like this-

```
AdRequest mAdRequest;
mAdRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();


enter code here
```

this line not show ad.

Comment: have u try new ads from admob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use these line in your code 
first...

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

// Create the interstitial.
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
```

then use this lines of code

```
// Create ad request.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

// Begin loading your interstitial.
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and whenever you want to show add call this method

```
// Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an      interstitial.

public void displayInterstitial() {
  if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
    interstitial.show();
  }
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: issue get resolved...as i providing MD5 hash value of device id....thnks for d reply